# multiple select drop down gets reset when calling window.print()

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I happened to notice that my multiple select dropdowns are getting reset when I call the window.print() function on the click of a button to print the current page.
This seems to have been working on Chrome v80 but it seems the issue is part of v81. 
I am using a workaround for this by displaying values in an input box (rather than the multiple select tag) on the print button click. I was wondering if there is a better solution to the issue.

A sample code is given below: Selected option values are retained in Chrome v80 but not on v81 when the print button is clicked.

```
        <html>
        <head>
            <script>
                function printPage(){
                    window.print();
                }
            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <select id="test" name="test" multiple>
                <option value="1">My val 1</option>
                <option value="2" selected>My val 2</option>
                <option value="3">My val 3</option>
                <option value="4" selected>My val 4</option>
                <option value="5">My val 5</option>
            </select>
            <input type="button" value="print" onclick="printPage()"/>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: @DWR: Bingo! Seems it was the print page setting. Backgroud graphics was unchecked. Worked like a charm. Could you please add your comment as an answer so that I could upvote it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your issue that the elements do not appear selected in the printout, or that after pressing print, the page forgets what was selected and the user must select them again? If it is just about appearing in the printout, it is possible you have "background graphics" unchecked in the "more options" section of the print dialog